# Create unique ID before calling upload function and pass it always for one person

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a registration form in which user can upload multiple files. He can upload ten files once and one by one each. Now what I want is that to create the `uniqueId` before calling the upload function and pass it to the upload function for the `mkdir()`.
Right now I am creating the unique Id in the upload function but don't want this actually.

```
 <form target="upload_target" id="fileupload" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_file/upload_it'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-warning">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" class="upload" />
</div>
    <input id="uploadFile" style="width: 160px; margin-top: 30px;float: left;height: 35px;" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
    <button id="btnupload" style="padding: 4.5px; float:left;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>

</form> 


function upload_it()

{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $uniqueID = uniqid(); 
    mkdir("application/uploads/".$uniqueID);

    $config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads/'.$uniqueID;
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

    $data['upload_data'] = '';
    if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload('files')) {
        $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    } 
    else
    {
          $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
    }
    $this->load->vars($data);

    $this->load->view('upload');
}
```

Comment: You can call `uniqid()` within the form like `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>" name="uniqId" />` and then can access it as form value. This way it will run once for all the 10 files the user is going to upload. There are other ways as well like store it in a session variable and check if a value is in the session variable and discard the session variable after everything is done.
NOTE: Make sure that you call `unique()` the right way.

Comment: But what if user browse 5 files and upload then again browse and upload 5 more files. Have a look on the form once I have edited the post.

Comment: Then you have to generate the unique id and store it in session like: `if(!isset($_SESSION['uniqid]){   $_SESSION{'uniqid'] = uniqid(); }` and the line `$uniqueID = uniqid();` in your upload function will become `$uniqueID = $_SESSION['uniqid'];`. Now once the user uploads all the 10 files then just destroy the session variable.

Comment: Will do it in the hidden form hidden input field `if(!isset($_SESSION['uniqid']){ $_SESSION{'uniqid'] = uniqid(); }` ?

Comment: You are welcome. Write `if(!isset($_SESSION['uniqid']){ $_SESSION{'uniqid'] = uniqid(); }` on the top of the page and in hidden field use `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uniqid']; ?>" name="uniqId" />`

Comment: I have added that line in the View file on the top of the page. then this `$uniqueID = $_SESSION['uniqid'];` in the controller. In the input type the `$unqiueid` remains same for all the uploads but the issue is that it is giving undefined variable _SESSION for `$uniqueID = $_SESSION['uniqid'];. ` What to do now? As i am using Codeigniter framework so is there any specific way to handle session variables in it

Comment: This is not the right MVC approach. The function should be in your controller not in the view. I don't know much about codeigniter but I think you have to load the session library first as ` $this->load->library('session');` (Depending if you auto-load the session library or not). Then you can manipulate session variables like `$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');`. I will strictly suggest to follow proper MVC and move this function to your controller. Hope it helps :)

Comment: What I did is create the session in the view and the variable u echoed in the input hidden file i passed it in the action of the form and then did `$uniqueID = $this->uri->segment(3);` and Its done. In the next try will move it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniqueID = uniqid(); 
mkdir("application/uploads/".$uniqueID);

function upload_it($upload_path)

{
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

    $data['upload_data'] = '';
    if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload('files')) {
        $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    } 
    else
    {
          $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
    }
    $this->load->vars($data);

    $this->load->view('upload');
}
```

Comment: Where to call the function in controller. Sorry i couldn't understand.

Comment: @BinteHava - it is a different question now after your edit. Take a look at **Think Different**'s comments as this is the answer you're looking for now.